# How to display fractional expression like this?

Tags: output-formatting, customization, boxes

For example:

The default output is

[image]

I want to the output display like

[image]

I noticed that `FractionBoxOptions`, but couldn't find a appropriate options.

Comment: The box language can be applied, but it is rather heavy and requires an additional programming. You need to have good reasons to refuse form the usual way in favor for the box language. It is not quite clear: where do you want to display the result in this form? And what for?  I guess you are quite familiar with the typesetting using palettes, are you? Do you need that the output is in this form right after the evaluation? What for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case it is sufficient to add a custom formatting rule:

```
MakeBoxes[Times[Rational[n_, d_], expr__], StandardForm] := 
 FractionBox[ToBoxes[Times[n, expr]], d]
```

Now

```
Solve[x^2 - 3 x + 1 == 0]
```

[image: screenshot]